# Bash: Multiple Lines from File Into One Command Argument

Tags: bash, shell

I need to pass multiple lines from one file into a script as one comma separated argument. Whenever I try to use the output of processing the file as a single string, the commas become separators. How can I do this?

Test case:

```
[user@host]$ #Here is a word list, my target words are on lines starting with "1,"
[user@host]$ cat word_list_numbered.txt
1,lakin
2,chesterfield
3,sparkplug
4,unscrawling
5,sukkah
1,girding
2,gripeful
3,historied
4,hypoglossal
5,nonmathematician
1,instructorship
2,loller
3,containerized
4,duodecimally
5,oligocythemia
1,nonsegregation
2,expecter
3,enterrologist
4,tromometry
5,salvia
[user@host]$ #Here is a mock operation, it just outputs the number of args, I want all selected words as one argument
[user@host]$ cat operation.sh
echo "This script has $# arguments"
[user@host]$ #Here is a script that outputs the needed words as comma delimited
[user@host]$ grep '^1,' word_list_numbered.txt | tr -d '1,' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'        lakin,girding,instructorship,nonsegregation[user@host]$
[user@host]$ #Here is the operation script receiving that comma delimited list
[user@host]$ ./operation.sh $(grep '^1,' word_list_numbered.txt | tr -d '1,' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
This script has 4 arguments
[user@host]$ #oops, too many arguments
[user@host]$ ./operation.sh foo,bar
This script has 1 arguments
[user@host]$ ./operation.sh foo bar
This script has 2 arguments
[user@host]$
```

Details:

- The needed words are in lines starting with 1,
- All words should be passed to operation.sh as one comma-delimited argument
- I don't have control over the format of word_list_numbered.txt or the need for operation.sh to take all words as one comma-delimited argument
- It is not optimal to run operation.sh many times--I'm asking this question so I don't have to do that

Comment: Your foo,bar test would seem to cover this possibility but since I can't reproduce this, what is the value of `$IFS` on your system?

Comment: @swornabsent Yes, I did go down the $IFS route. It is apparently set to newline:

Comment: @msw I'm attempting to: select the words in all lines starting with "1,"; concatenate them delimited by commas; apply them as an argument for operation.sh

Comment: Why did every answer here get a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a combination of awk and xargs?

```
 awk -F, -v ORS=, '$1==1{print $2}' file | xargs ./operation.sh
```

Or if you mind the trailing comma:

```
 awk -F, -v ORS=, '$1==1{print $2}' file | sed 's/,$//' | xargs ./operation.sh
```

Test:

```
$ cat operation.sh 
echo "This script has $# arguments"
echo "$@"

$ awk -F, -v ORS=, '$1==1{print $2}' file | sed 's/,$//' | xargs ./operation.sh 
This script has 1 arguments
lakin,girding,instructorship,nonsegregation

$ cat file
1,lakin
2,chesterfield
3,sparkplug
4,unscrawling
5,sukkah
1,girding
2,gripeful
3,historied
4,hypoglossal
5,nonmathematician
1,instructorship
2,loller
3,containerized
4,duodecimally
5,oligocythemia
1,nonsegregation
2,expecter
3,enterrologist
4,tromometry
5,salvia
```

---

Without xargs it would be:

```
./operation.sh "$(awk -F, -v ORS=, '$1==1{print $2}' file | sed 's/,$//')"
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this. I think the key part to your response is either piping or putting double-quotes around the parsing script. The piping or quotes seem to force the result to be treated as a string. I can pip or put double-quotes around my grep/tr/sed parsing script and get one argument too. Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `awk` would be using **command substitution** in bash to fill an array with the contents of your file and then again to join all lines into a single comma separated string to pass to `operation.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

## function simulating operation.sh
operation() { printf "%s\n" "$1"; }

a=( $(<word_list_numbered.txt) )
b="${a[0]}$(printf ",%s" ${a[@]:1} )"

operation $b

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash csvlist.sh
1,lakin,2,chesterfield,3,sparkplug,4,unscrawling, ..<snip>.. 5,salvia
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
1,lakin
2,chesterfield
3,sparkplug
4,unscrawling
5,sukkah
1,girding
2,gripeful
3,historied
4,hypoglossal
5,nonmathematician
1,instructorship
2,loller
3,containerized
4,duodecimally
5,oligocythemia
1,nonsegregation
2,expecter
3,enterrologist
4,tromometry
5,salvia
```

In Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -F',' -lane '$A[++$#A]=$F[1] if $F[0]=="1"; END{ print join(",", @A) }'
lakin,girding,instructorship,nonsegregation
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this problem. Wow, if I could think in Perl I'd certainly be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

filter and get the words by awk and join them by using paste.

```
$ awk -F ',' '$1==1{print $2}' word_list_numbered.txt  | paste -s -d ',' -
lakin,girding,instructorship,nonsegregation
$ ./operation.sh "$(awk -F ',' '$1==1{print $2}' word_list_numbered.txt  | paste -s -d ',' - )"
This script has 1 arguments
$
```

UPDATE: enclosed using double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this problem! That's a very nice use of paste--I'm always on the lookout for a new way to use it. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me until I put the output in double-quotes as in @user000001's answer.